# How to add initial filter to BootstrapGridView in razor

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress

When the page loads, I need to already have a filter in place for a given column.

Here is a sample:

```
@(Html.DevExpress()
             .BootstrapGridView<SomeViewModel>("SomeName")
             ... //other settings
             .Columns(columns => 
             {
                 columns.AddCommandColumn() 
                        .ShowSelectCheckbox(true)
                        .SelectAllCheckboxMode(GridViewSelectAllCheckBoxMode.AllPages);
                 ... //some other columns
                 columns.Add(m => m.SomeBoolProperty).Caption("SomeCaption");
             })
             ... //other settings
 )
```

Ok, now I need the column of "SomeBoolProperty" to have a filter already in place when the grid loads (let's say I want to have only "checked"/true entries to appear in the grid - the model should still have them all, obviously, otherwise I'd do it in the controller). Can I do that in razor somehow? From what I've seen I can change filter templates but can I actually physically add a filter? If not how else could I do this, maybe in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way in the end, like this:

```
@(Html.DevExpress()
         .BootstrapGridView<SomeViewModel>("SomeName")
         ... //other settings

         .OnInitialized((s, e) =>
                {
                    s.AutoFilterByColumn(s.DataColumns["SomeBoolProperty"], "true");
                })

         ... //other settings
         .Columns(columns => 
         {
             columns.AddCommandColumn() 
                    .ShowSelectCheckbox(true)
                    .SelectAllCheckboxMode(GridViewSelectAllCheckBoxMode.AllPages);
             ... //some other columns
             columns.Add(m => m.SomeBoolProperty).Caption("SomeCaption");
         })
         ... //other settings
 )
```

By adding OnInitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **SettingsHeaderFilter** property, you can add filtering mode to the column header, if your column is boolean type, then **GridHeaderFilterMode.CheckedList** will solve in this case.

```
columns.Add(m => m.SomeBoolProperty)
            .Caption("SomeCaption")
                .SettingsHeaderFilter(settings => settings
                    .Mode(GridHeaderFilterMode.CheckedList));
```

Documentation: [Header Filter - Checked List mode](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspnetcore-bootstrap/GridView-Filtering#GridViewHeaderFilterWithCheckedListMode)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. I think this influences how the filtering happens when users do it, but it doesn't add any filters in code, which is what I need

Comment: I see only two ways, you can treat this in your controller as you mentioned or try working with the lambda expression in the middle of the code in your razor page.